# Get text with BeautifulSoup CSS Selector

Tags: python, python-2.7, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Example HTML

```
<h2 id="name">
    ABC
    <span class="numbers">123</span>
    <span class="lower">abc</span>
</h2>
```

I can get the numbers with something like:

```
soup.select('#name > span.numbers')[0].text
```

How do I get the text `ABC` using BeautifulSoup and the `select` function?

What about in this case?

```
<div id="name">
    <div id="numbers">123</div> 
    ABC
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the first case, get the [previous sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.select_one('#name > span.numbers').previous_sibling
```

In the second case, get the [next sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.select_one('#name > #numbers').next_sibling
```

Note that I assume that it is intentional that here you have the `numbers` as an `id` value and the tag is `div` instead of `span`. Hence, I've adjusted the CSS selector.

---

To cover both cases, you can go to the parent of the tag and find the non-empty text node in a non-recursive mode:

```
parent = soup.select_one('#name > .numbers,#numbers').parent
print(parent.find(text=lambda text: text and text.strip(), recursive=False).strip())
```

Note the change in the selector - we are asking to match either `numbers` id or `numbers` class.

Though, I have a feeling that this universal solution would not be quite reliable because, for starters, I don't know what your real inputs could be.

Comment: Yes, the change in the id and div versus span was intentional. Thanks for noticing! Is there a way to start with the parent as in your last solution and then select directly for the first child in case #1 or for the second child in case #2? I am trying to avoid using find or findAll.

Comment: @slaw yeah, sure, you can just use the `contents` list: `tag.contents[0]` or `tag.contents[1]`. Or, go through the `tag.children` generator.