# Unable to loop through navigable string with BeautifulSoup CSS Selector

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I would like to extract the content inside the *p* tag below.

```
<section id="abstractSection" class="row">
<h3 class="h4">Abstract<span id="viewRefPH" class="pull-right hidden"></span>
</h3>
<p> Variation of the  (<span class="ScopusTermHighlight">EEG</span>), has functional and. behavioural effects in sensory <span class="ScopusTermHighlight">EEG</span We can interpret our. Individual <span class="ScopusTermHighlight">EEG</span> text to extract <span class="ScopusTermHighlight">EEG</span> power level.</p>
</section>
```

A one line `Selenium` as below,

```
document_abstract = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="abstractSection"]/p'))).text
```

can extract easily the *p* tag content and provide the following output:

```
Variation of the EEG, has functional and. behavioural effects in sensoryEEG. We can interpret our. Individual EEG text to extract EEG power level.
```

Nevertheless, I would like to employ the `BeautifulSoup` due to speed consideration.

The following `bs` by referring to the css selector (i.e.,`#abstractSection` ) was tested

```
url = r'scopus_offilne_specific_page.html'
with open(url, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    page_soup = soup(f, 'html.parser')
    home=page_soup.select_one('#abstractSection').next_sibling
    for item in home:
        for a in item.find_all("p"):
            print(a.get_text())
```

However, the compiler return the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Also, since [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/21100200805?origin=recordpage) require login id, the above problem can be reproduce by using the offline html which is accessible via this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10uNixXKDqibtDjMQDTcF3wZYsD4PYZGJ/view?usp=sharing).

May I know where did I do wrong, appreciate for any insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37873059/6446053), the problem issued above apparently can be solve simply as below

```
document_abstract=page_soup.select('#abstractSection > p')[0].text
```