# Web scraping table data using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping in Python for a project using Beautiful Soup by doing the following:
Scraping Kansas City Chiefs active team player name with the college attended. This is the url used https://www.chiefs.com/team/players-roster/.

After compiling, I get an error saying "IndexError: list index out of range".

I don't know if my set classes are wrong. Help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.chiefs.com/team/players-roster/"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

roster_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'd3-o-table d3-o-table--row-striping d3-o-table--detailed d3-o-table--sortable {sortlist: [[0,0]]}')

for person in roster_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = person.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        player_name = row.find('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected"')
        player_university = row.find_all('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected')[7].text
        print(player_name,player_university)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always post the __complete error output__ (including traceback). It may show the line-number or statement in your code, where the error-happened.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a `td` with class `sorter-lastname selected` in the source code. You basically need the last `td` in each row, so this would do:

```
for person in roster_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = person.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        player_name = row.find('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected"')
        player_university = row.find_all('td')[-1].text
```

PS. scraping tables is extremely easy in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.chiefs.com/team/players-roster/')
df[0].to_cvs('output.csv')
```

It may take a bit longer, but the output is impressive, for example the `print(df[0])`:

```
               Player     # Pos    HT   WT  Age Exp            College
0       Josh Pederson   NaN  TE   6-5  235   24   R   Louisiana-Monroe
1   Brandin Dandridge   NaN  WR  5-10  180   25   R   Missouri Western
2       Justin Watson   NaN  WR   6-3  215   25   4       Pennsylvania
3    Jonathan Woodard   NaN  DE   6-5  271   28   3   Central Arkansas
4     Andrew Billings   NaN  DT   6-1  311   26   5             Baylor
..                ...   ...  ..   ...  ...  ...  ..                ...
84   James Winchester  41.0  LS   6-3  242   32   7           Oklahoma
85       Travis Kelce  87.0  TE   6-5  256   32   9         Cincinnati
86        Marcus Kemp  85.0  WR   6-4  208   26   4             Hawaii
87        Chris Jones  95.0  DT   6-6  298   27   6  Mississippi State
88    Harrison Butker   7.0   K   6-4  196   26   5       Georgia Tech

[89 rows x 8 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Two issues to solve: (1) indexing, (2) HTML element-queries

### Indexing

The Python *Index Operator* is represented by opening and closing square brackets: `[]`. The syntax, however, requires you to put a *number* inside the brackets.

**Example:**
So `[7]` applies indexing to the preceding *iterable* (all found `td`s), to get the element with index 7. In Python indices are 0-based, so they start with 0 for the first element.

In your statement, you take all found cells as `<td>` HTML-elements of the specific classes as *iterable* and want to get the 8th element, by indexing with `[7]`.

```
row.find_all('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected')[7]
```

#### How to avoid index-errors ?

Are you sure there are any `td` elements found in the `row`?
If some are found, can we guarantee that it are always at least 8.

In this case, the were apparently less than 8 elements.

That's why Python would raise an `IndexError`, e.g. in given script line 15:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
    player_university = row.find_all('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected')[7].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Better **test on length** before indexing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.chiefs.com/team/players-roster/"

html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

roster_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'd3-o-table d3-o-table--row-striping d3-o-table--detailed d3-o-table--sortable {sortlist: [[0,0]]}')

for person in roster_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = person.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        print(f"person row: {row}")  # debug-print helps to fix element-query
        player_name = row.find('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected"')
        cells = row.find_all('td', class_='sorter-lastname selected')
        player_university = None   # define a default to avoid NameError
        if len(cells) > 7:   # test on minimum length of 8 for index 7
            player_university = cells[7].text
        print(player_name, player_university)
```

### Element-queries

When the index was fixed, the queried names returned empty results as `None, None`.

We need to debug (thus I added the print inside the loop) and adjust the queries:
(1) for the *university-name*:
If you follow [RJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71071200/5730279) and choose the **last cell without any class-condition**  then a negative index like `-1` means from backwards, like here: the last. The number of cells should be at least 1 or greater than 0.

(2) for the *player-name*:
It appears to be in the first cell (also with a CSS-class for sorting), nested either in a link-title `<a .. title="Player Name">` or in following sibling as inner text of `span > a`.

#### CSS selectors

You may use [**CSS selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) for that an bs4's `select` or `select_one` functions. Then you can select the path like `td > ? > ? > a` and `get` the title.

Note: the `?`  placeholders are left as challenging exercise for you.)

**️ Tip:** most browsers have an inspector (right click on the element, e.g. the player-name), then choose "inspect element" and an HTML source view opens selecting the element. Right-click again to "Copy" the element as "CSS selector".

### Further Reading

About indexing, and the magic of negative numbers like `[-1]`:

- AskPython: [Indexing in Python - A Complete Beginners Guide](https://www.askpython.com/python/list/indexing-in-python)

.. a bit further, about *slicing*:

- Real Python: [Indexing and Slicing](https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/)

Research on Beautiful Soup here:

- [Using BeautifulSoup to extract the title of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542549/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-the-title-of-a-link)
- [Get text with BeautifulSoup CSS Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873059/get-text-with-beautifulsoup-css-selector)